# Limiting behavior of a solution of Abel equation of the first kind

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, asymptotics

In my work, I encountered the following special Abel ode of the first kind:
$$f^\prime(x)=-f^3(x)+f^2(x)-\frac{1}{x+2}f(x)+1,~~~f(0)=1.$$
I want to know if the limit $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)$ exists without solving it. I got to know from some references, generally, that it is hard to find its explicit solution (even implicit solution), but as we see, this ode I asked has a quite special form. I intuitively think that it has finite limit.But how to prove or disprove?

Any comments are highly appreciated!

Comment: $x+2\sim x$ as $x \to \infty$

Comment: thanks  Sal. Yes, I have also noticed this relation, but is it helpful for the existence of limit I asked? any more details?

Comment: Let $g(x)$ be the real root of $-y^3 + y^2 - y/(x + 2) + 1$. If $f(x) < g(x)$, then $f'(x) > 0$. If $x_0$ is the leftmost point where $f(x_0) = g(x_0)$, then $f'(x_0) = 0$ and $f''(x_0) = f(x_0)/(x_0 + 2)^2 > 0$. But this is impossible, since $f$ is increasing in a left neighborhood of $x_0$. Therefore $f$ is increasing and is bounded from above by $g$. Since $f$ cannot blow up in finite time, the interval of existence extends to infinity. Since the limits of $f$ and $f'$ exist and the limit of $f$ is finite, the limit of $f'$ is zero, from which we find the limit of $f$.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! Maxim. It is very helpful and easy to understand.